# invalid writes valgrind causing segmentation fault

Tags: c++, debugging, vector, segmentation-fault

I am trying to create a maze class that can read an input stream that has the description of the maze and return a maze. However when I run a test with this given input stream:

```
20 10
####################
#................<.#
#..................#
#...###............#
#.....#............#
#.....#............#
#...###............#
#..................#
#..................#
####################
```

It gives a segmentation fault, and I run the object file on valgrind to check what is happening:

```
Invalid write of size 8
==2482545==    at 0x4032CD: Maze::setTile(Position const&, Tile*) (maze.cpp:47)
==2482545==    by 0x40347B: Maze::read(std::istream&) (maze.cpp:67)
.....
==2482545==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

I don't really understand why there is an segmentation fault or an invalid write, in my code, I should have allocated the space for each tile inside my setTile function, so there should be space for me to write. I also stacked the tile_collection with my constructor so tile_collection should be initialized when I called Maze(20,10), and the resizing inside setTile should be working. Can you please point out what am I missing? Thank you in advance. I know that I asked a really similar question 3 hours ago but I am still stuck on this invalid write.(The Position class and tilefactory class are 2 given files so they should work fine)
This is the class declared in header file:

```
class Maze {
private:
  // TODO: add fields
  int Width;
  int Height;
  std::vector<Tile*> tile_collection;
```

This is my cpp file:

```
Maze::Maze(int width,int height):
  Width(width),Height(height){
  tile_collection[(width-1)*(height)];
}

}


void Maze::setTile(const Position &pos,Tile *tile){
  tile_collection[pos.getX()+pos.getY()*(Width)]=tile;
}


Maze *Maze::read(std::istream &in){
  int x;int y;char c;
  if ((in>>x)&&(in>>y)){
      Maze *new_maze=new Maze(x,y);
      //loop over the specified maze dimension
        for (int i=0;i<y;i++){
          for (int j=0;j<x;j++){
            if (in>>c){
              //using tilefactory to change character into a tile
              TileFactory *fac=TileFactory::getInstance();
              Tile* temp=fac->createFromChar(c);
              //if createFromChar fails, return nullptr, otherwise set tile at position j,i
              if (temp==nullptr){
                return nullptr;
              }
              else{
                new_maze->setTile(Position(j,i),temp);
              }
            }
          }
        }
        return new_maze;
  }
  else{
    return nullptr;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I think it is this line: tile_collection[pos.getX()+pos.getY()*(Width)]=tile; but I should have defined  tile_collection[(width-1)*(height)] at the constructor

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the fault you are seeing is a consequence of this line:

```
          TileFactory *fac=fac->getInstance();
```

You're declaring a local pointer-variable named `fac` but you are trying to call a method (`getInstance()`) through that same pointer-variable before it's even been set to anything.  Seems like a recipe for disaster to me!

Comment: Umm I think the constructor is disallowed for the TileFactory class, so I am only able to get an instance of it

Comment: If it is a static method, the correct way to call it is `TileFactory * fac = TileFactory::getInstance();`

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it and recompiled it but I still receive the invalid write error at this line:  tile_collection[pos.getX()+pos.getY()*(Width)]=tile; but I am wondering since I declared my tile_collection at the constructor, this shouldn't be a null ptr; I really struggle to find out where is the problem

Comment: You can check to see if it's a NULL pointer or not... add a temporary debug-print command just before that line, something like `fprintf(stderr, "DEBUG this=%p  tile=%p\n", this, tile);` and then look at your program's output just before it crashes to see if any of the printed pointer values are `0x0`

Comment: Btw `tile_collection` can't be NULL since it is not a pointer.

Comment: You might also add a `fprintf(stderr, "DEBUG about to write to slot %i/%zu\n", pos.getX()+pos.getY()*(Width), tile_collection.size());` -- just to make sure that the calculated index into the std::vector is actually a valid index and not negative or greater than the number of slots available.